# OCaml analogue to Python's String join method

Tags: ocaml

Given a list of string elements in Python, I can concatenate these elements with specified glue. For example:

```
' '.join(["phd", "in", "everything"])
```

evaluates to the string `"phd in everything"`.

What analogue in OCaml is considered most idiomatic? That is, *how may string elements of a list be joined with some specified string* in OCaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent in Ocaml is :

```
#String.concat " " ["phd"; "in"; "everything"]
```

There is no restriction vs the length of the list.